# STL way to add a constant value to a std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an algorithm in the standard library that can add a value to each element of a std::vector? 
Something like

```
std::vector<double> myvec(5,0.);
std::add_constant(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 1.);
```

that adds the value 1.0 to each element?

If there isn't a nice (e.g. short, beautiful, easy to read) way to do this in STL, how about boost?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers - I edited the question to represent what I am actually looking for better - an easy-to-read portable way to achieve this

Comment: either answer you have so far will work on any C++03-conforming compiler.  I think the reason `std::add_constant` doesn't exist is because it's pretty easy to write your own.  C++ isn't a functional language, so doing stuff like this is a little clunky.

Comment: @Kristo, true, its easy to write it yourself, but the one you write yourself isn't going to be fast. I am looking for something that is similar to BLAS functionality: An easy-to-read interface hiding a complex algorithm which might for example use multithreading or other features.

Comment: it's likely to be faster than a hand-rolled `for` loop for large vectors, thanks to compiler inlining.  To parallelize the "add 1 to every element" operation you're going to need a separate library or custom solution tuned to your hardware.  Remember: make sure you profile it before you decide it's too slow.

Comment: you should look at the uBlas library in boost, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm, maybe you'll find something useful there...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Take a look at `std::for_each` and `std::transform`.  The latter accepts three iterators (the begin and end of a sequence, and the start of the output sequence) and a function object.  There are a couple of ways to write this.  One way, using nothing but standard stuff, is:

```
transform(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec.begin(),
          bind2nd(std::plus<double>(), 1.0));
```

You can do it with `for_each` as well, but the default behavior of `std::plus` won't write the answer back to the original vector.  In that case you have to write your own functor.  Simple example follows:

```
struct AddVal
{
    double val;
    AddVal(double v) : val(v);

    void operator()(double &elem) const
    {
        elem += v;
    }
};

std::for_each(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), AddVal(1.0));
```

Comment: That's a fast one! :) I'm late, so let me just drop http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/ .

Comment: Cool. Faster than me, too. Also as page says, faster even than OP! "asked 1 min ago", "answered 2 mins ago"

Comment: :) You made the same mistake I did, only one tweak, `plus<double>`

Comment: hej! now you just added my answer to your answer! unfair :p

Comment: BTW, that's a fun approach - drop a very vague answer with the remark "I'm going to edit and elaborate", and then give the complete answer. Reminds me of saying "First! This question is MINE! Now just give me a few minutes to answer it!" :)))

Comment: @Kos, the OP also gets something immediately to get started while I type up a more complete answer.

Comment: @Itjax, I've been in the process of editing my answer this whole time.  I discovered (about the same time you posted your answer) that `std::plus` doesn't modify its arguments, so you have to use `std::transform`.  +1 to your answer for being very concise and, of course, correct!

Comment: I have seen some discussions on whether `for_each` should be used to change the contents of the container or not, with some people defending that while it does work in different implementations, the standard does not guarantee that usage of `for_each`... I did not quite understand the reason, so I cannot say anything else, but use `transform` if you can :)

Comment: @David: from n3225 (C++0x FCD), 25.2.4 [alg.foreach], note 2: *Note: If the type of first satisfies the requirements of a
mutable iterator, f may apply nonconstant functions through the dereferenced iterator.—end note*

Comment: std::bind2nd is deprecated as of C++11, and will be removed in C++17. Consider `std::transform(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec.begin(), [&](double x){x+1.0;});`

Comment: @Paamand: slight correction to include the return: `std::transform(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), myvec.begin(), [&](double x){return(x+1.0);});`

Answer (score 60):

Even shorter using lambda functions, if you use C++0x:

```
std::for_each(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), [](double& d) { d+=1.0;});
```

Answer (score 14):

The shortest way in plain C++0X is :

```
for(double& d : myvec)
  d += 1.0;
```

and with boost :

```
for_each(myvec, _1 += 1.0); // boost.range + boost.lambda
```

Comment: Very nice answer!

Answer (score 9):

```
std::transform( myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), 
                myvec.begin(), std::bind2nd( std::plus<double>(), 1.0 ) );
```

Comment: You beat me to it by 30s, I've removed my answer! :)

Comment: You can also use a lambda as the functor: like []( double x ) { return x + 1.0; } if you got c++0x, or boost::bind( std::plus<double>(), _1, 1.0 )

Comment: Fun typing saver: thanks to [Koenig Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenig_lookup), you can eliminate all but the innermost `std::` in your code and it'll still work.

Comment: It is deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind12

Answer (score 6):

If you're interested in performing lots of math on vectors, you might want to look into the [`<valarray>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/) part of the standard library.  It's basically a `std::vector<>` designed for vectorial numerical computations (slices, math functions, point-wise operators, etc.).

The only part that really sucks is it doesn't have easy conversions to and from `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Valarray ftw! It gets way too little attention for math-related stuff.

Comment: @rubenvb: indeed, it's one of the least known parts of the library.  Unfortunately, the interface is clumsy for anything that's not math.  The standard comity could have at least added iterators and a range constructor for easy conversion to/from other containers.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to add `std::transform()` and lambda expression.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    
std::vector<double> myVector;
double constantElement;
std::transform(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myVector.begin(), [&](auto& value){ return value+constantElement; });
```